# Is a new object created always for a RestEasy webservice class?

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resteasy, jboss6.x

We are using ReastEasy with JBoss EAP 6.x. I want to know if a new object is always created for every http request. If yes, how can I stop JBoss creating new objects for every request?

I annotated a void method in my web service class with `javax.annotation.@PostConstruct` to check if a new object is always being created. For my amusement the method itself was not called. Then I understood that the servlet container is managing my web service classes and that is why the `@PostConstruct` is not called. Am I right?

Can anyone please point me to some resources which explains the webservice life cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I want to know if a new object is always created for every http request"*

Yes. See section [3.1.1 Lifecycle and Environment](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec.html), in the JAX-RS spec:

> By default a new resource class instance is created for each request to that resource.

---

> *"If yes, how can I stop jboss creating new objects for every request?"*

One way is to override `getSingletons()` in `Application` subclass, which returns a `Set` of resources and providers you want to be only created once. See [Resteasy Doc](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.7.Final/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html#javax.ws.rs.core.Application) for more information on deployment options. For example

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
    private final Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

    public RestApplication(){
        singletons.add(new SingletnResourceClass());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons(){
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

---

> *"Then I understood that the servlet container is managing my web service classes and that is why the @PostConstruct is not called. Am I right?"*

That annotation in Java EE is handled by CDI, and in JBoss, we should have a `beans.xml` file in the `WEB-INF` to enable the CDI module.

---

> *"Can anyone please point me to some resources which explains the webservice life cycle?"*

The first link above has some explanation

Comment: I have beans.xml in my `WEB-INF` directory.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I wanted to point out: you can annotate your resource as `@Singleton` (javax.inject.Singleton) to have it created only once.

This is also mentioned [in the documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2643):

> @Singleton: In this scope there is only one instance per jax-rs application.
>   Singleton resource can be either annotated with @Singleton and its
>   class can be registered using the instance of Application. You can
>   also create singletons by registering singleton instances into
>   Application.